# LibreOffice Calc goes grey takes lots of CPU cycles

Tags: libreoffice

When working on the Calc (spreadsheet) many time the screen goes grey and CPU cycle shoots up to 100% for a very long time and the app is not responsive. Also slows down other open apps etc due to CPU being at 100%. Is there anyway this can be avoided?

The file size doesn't really matter as it happens with having only one sheet with simple data as well as file with several sheets and calculations. Running Ubuntu 11.10 on a Dell Inspiron 1300 with 2 GB ram and Intel Celeron 1.5 GHz CPU. Long time sometimes over 2 mins. I haven't used Top but can give it a try if I knew what it is

- Changing the Graphic cache user for liberoffice did not really change anything.

Comment: The file size doesn't really matter as it happens with having only one sheet with simple data as well as file with several sheets and calculations. Running Ubuntu 11.10 on a Dell Inspiron 1300 with 2 GB ram and Intel Celeron 1.5 GHz CPU. Long time sometimes over 2 mins. I haven't used Top but can give it a try if I knew what it is :-)

Comment: Could it be that there's a formula that's faulty? Is there a formula common to all your problematic sheets or files? And you can use the `man` command to see what `top` does. You would type `man top` in a terminal. `Top` is present by default on your Ubuntu.

Comment: I have the same problem with Calc.  Just scrolling through big spreadsheet selecting rows.  Tried the Anti-aliasing and graphics cache below, with no effect.  Where should we log this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Open any LibreOffice application. In the Tool-bar under "Tools" use the drop-down and open "options" look for "memory". This setting as well as others will help limit CPU cycles and decrease lag time.
[image]

Comment: I'm just wondering whether reducing the `Use for LibreOffice` in `Graphics cache` will help or have the opposite effect. I've sometimes encountered problems similar to what OP has reported, but then mostly with `Writer` and rarely with `Calc`. The settings are as shown in the graphic above. The OS is 11.10 (Unity 3D) on a Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop with 4 GB RAM. I don't do too many things at one time ... maybe listen to music (Totem), have a few tabs open in Firefox and LibreOffice. My non-technical opinion is that there are some situations that cause LibreOffice to go crazy.

Comment: Changing the Graphic cache user for liberoffice did not really change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I've found workaround: go to "Tools/Options/View" and uncheck "Graphics output: Anti-aliasing". Works for me. I've posted bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/947833). Maybe it's your case too.